# Removing a switch

Tags: electrical, switch, wire

I have a light switch that turns on an electrical outlet. I want to remove the light switch completely and leave the electrical outlet always "on".

When I turned the power off to the room and unscrewed the light switch, i noticed 3 black wires: 2 of them were screwed on the same side of the switch on different screws, but there was a 3rd black wire that was connected to the back (pushed in and held by a spring).

I was thinking the 2 wires made sense, that switch, when turned on would connect the wire together, and when off would break the connection. So I thought connecting the 2 wires would always leave that electrical outlet on. But now I'm a bit confused because I dont know what that 3rd black wire does and what the next steps are?

Picture: the switch to the right controls the light on the ceiling. The switch on the left that I want removed use to control under cabinet lights in the laundry, but I removed those and installed electrical outlets instead.

As you can see I already removed the 2 black wires and capped them in the mean time.  I was thinking I would need to connect them together and this would make the outlet 'on', but thought I'd ask here first!
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a photo of the other side of the switch in question?

Answer (score 3):

### First you must check the building codes.

The building codes absolutely require a light switch in one of the usual and expected locations (for instance right outside a bathroom is just fine) --  and the switch must cause a light to turn on in the room.

It's fine if you hardly ever use it; *but it's gotta be there and it's gotta work*. (We rarely use ours, but we have rather bright bulbs in them because when you want light, you want it.)  One acceptable way to do this is have a switched receptacle and a light plugged into it.  Two other ways are motion sensors, or a light hardwired on 24x7 (which makes more sense now that they have 3-watt LEDs).

This is a safety issue to protect guests *including First Responders*.  Or to be more precise, help First Responders do their job: so the EMT can focus on intubating you, the fireman can look quickly and shout "Clear" and the cop can see that your son is holding a gaming mouse, not a gun.  This all makes perfect sense when you think about it.

So, when eliminating a switch like that, make sure there'll still be a switchable light.

### Then, wire the switch

When you find more wires than you expect on a switch (e.g. 3 on a plain, 4 on a 3-way), the first thing you should do is *pigtail* the switch.  Typically you have 2 wires on 1 "terminal".  Often, this is done by putting 1 wire on the screw and the other wire on the nearby backstab.  (Backstabs are highly unreliable; that alone is reason to pigtail.)

So, pull those two wires off, and wirenut them to each other with a pigtail to the switch.    Now your switch has the normal number of wires, and you can conceptualize it in the expected way.

If you know which wire(s) are always-hot vs switched-hot, I prefer to mark switched-hot wires with red electrical tape.   I also prefer to mark 3-way *travelers* (always 2 travelers coming off the brass screws into the same cable) both with yellow tape. This (especially marking travelers) makes life much easier when changing 3-way or smart switches.

Answer (score 2):

### Why did you have 3 wires?

There are two typical reasons why you would have 3 wires on one switch:

#### 3-Way Switch

A 3-way switch will have one wire that is either hot or switched-hot (depending on the position of the switch relative to the switched device) and two wires that are *travelers*.

If you have a 3-way switch then normally you will have *another* 3-way switch elsewhere. (Sometimes a 3-way switch will be used as a regular switch just because it was available, but then you will only have 2 wires.)

#### Power to Someplace Else

Very often power will go to one switch **and** on to another switch or unswitched receptacles or something else. If that's the case, you will have one hot "in", one hot "out" and a switched-hot. Very often people will use a backstab ("pushed in and held by a spring") simply as an easy way to get an extra wire connected to the switch instead of using pigtails and wire nuts.

### What do you have?

If the switch has only 2 screws, then it is a regular switch and this is definitely "power to someplace else".

If the switch has 3 screws then it is a 3-way switch. However, since your 3rd wire was on a backstab connection rather than a screw, the key question is *what color screws were used*? If they were the same color then the switch was used as a 3-way switch. If they were different colors *and the backstab wire was electrically connected to one of those two screws* (check with a multimeter) then it was used as a regular switch. If they were different colors and the backstab wire was electrically connected to the 3rd screw then it was used as a 3-way switch.

### What should you do?

If you have a regular switch then simply connect all 3 wires together. That will join the incoming hot, the outgoing (to someplace else) hot and the not-switched-any-more hot to the receptacles.

If you have a 3-way switch then you should try to identify the other 3-way switch - they normally come in pairs. Then *in place of both switches* pick one of the travelers and connect it to the hot wire and cap off (wire nut) the other traveler.